# How can I check if I can write to a file without elevated token?

Tags: security, winapi

I know that this question was asked by many other people, but my case has one important difference. I can't just open file handle with write option because I want to check if I can write in this file without elevated token.

For example, user can run my installer as administrator so I can write in almost all of folders, but after installation my program won't work.

I thought that I can just get the token of my process, disable all privileges and apply it to new thread. I did it but it doesn't work.

I don't want to include code that I wrote because there are a lot of insignificant stuff. Instead, I'll just describe order of functions that I use.

1. `GetCurrentProcess`
2. `OpenProcessToken`
3. `DuplicateTokenEx` - somebody told me that it removes the elevation
4. `AdjustTokenPrivileges` - I call it with `DisableAllPriveleges` = true
5. `CreateThread` - `Suspend` = true
6. `SetThreadToken`
7. `CreateFile`

I can still write to all folders. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `DuplicateTokenEx` not remove any elevation. somebody told false to you

Comment: than not need create new thread, you can impersonate current thread, and then revert to self, and finally possible use `AccessCheck` api

Comment: In my opinion I should remove elevation first. And I really don't understand what does elevation means. Is it some kind of privelege or something?  
In case of AccessCheck I don't know from where I should get SID. I have folder and I want to check if I can write to it. So do I have to get SID from file in this folder? It isn't exists in general case.

Comment: not sid but security descriptor - from object, access to which you want check access

Comment: Yes sorry I meant security descriptor but I still doesn't understand how to remove elevation.

Comment: you need call `CreateRestrictedToken(hToken, LUA_TOKEN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &hLuaToken)` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for create not elevated token from your existing token we can use [`CreateRestrictedToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-createrestrictedtoken) function with `LUA_TOKEN` flag. this by fact what is UAC doing when create restricted version of an existing access token on interactive logon. and then we can do access via this token. also note that we not need use new thread - we can temporary impersonate current thread with this lua token and then revert back.

so code can look like:

```
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

ULONG CheckFileWriteAccess(PCWSTR FileName, ULONG& dwFileError)
{
    HANDLE hToken, hLuaToken;

    ULONG dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken));

    if (dwError == NOERROR)
    {
        dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(CreateRestrictedToken(hToken, LUA_TOKEN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &hLuaToken));

        CloseHandle(hToken);

        if (dwError == NOERROR)
        {
            dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DuplicateToken(hLuaToken, ::SecurityImpersonation, &hToken));

            CloseHandle(hLuaToken);

            if (dwError == NOERROR)
            {
                dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(SetThreadToken(0, hToken));

                CloseHandle(hToken);

                if (dwError == NOERROR)
                {
                    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(FileName, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, 
                        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

                    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(hFile);
                        dwFileError = NOERROR;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dwFileError = GetLastError();
                        NTSTATUS status = RtlGetLastNtStatus();
                        if (RtlNtStatusToDosError(status) == dwFileError)
                        {
                            dwFileError = HRESULT_FROM_NT(status);
                        }
                    }

                    SetThreadToken(0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

note also snippet

```
dwFileError = GetLastError();
NTSTATUS status = RtlGetLastNtStatus();
if (RtlNtStatusToDosError(status) == dwFileError)
{
    dwFileError = HRESULT_FROM_NT(status);
}
```

win32 error returned from `CreateFileW` api - frequently confused, because many different (by sense) NTSTATUS errors mapped to single win32 error. so always better check `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead `GetLastError()`. even more better of course use [`NtOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntopenfile) (it documented, user mode, supported, will be not altered or removed) which direct return actual NTSTATUS.

note also that potential you can got error `STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION` too. more releable open file with `READ_CONTROL` only access (this never give sharing violation) query it security descriptor and than use [`AccessCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-accesscheck) with LUA token, but this require more complex code